# Configuring multiple jboss 7 instances on one machine & how to run at a time

Tags: jboss7.x

I'm configuring multiple JBoss 7 instances on one machine and running at the same time. Please provide step by step information about how I can change ports. I am using standalone-full-ha.xml.

Answer (score 2):

You set the system property `jboss.socket.binding.port-offset` and then the ports in `<socket-binding-group/>` are relative to this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried for two instances and only place I made changes was `socket-binding-group` tag in standalone.xml. You can find this tag at bottom of file.

Change ports for other instance in above tag and it should work like

```
<socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/> -- server1
<socket-binding name="http" port="8090"/> -- server2
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to create Multiple JBOSS standalone instances:

1. Create a copy of standalone and rename to `standalone_2`
2. Create copy of `standalone.bat` and rename as `standalone2.bat` file in bin folder and change the following:

   if "x%STANDALONE_CONF%" == "x" (
      set "STANDALONE_CONF=%DIRNAME%standalone.conf2.bat"
   )
3. Run the `standalone2.bat` file to start the standalone 2.
4. Create a copy of `standalone.conf.bat` file and rename as `standalone.conf2.bat` file in bin folder and add below line to point base directory as standalone1 folder.

   set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djboss.server.base.dir=standalone_2"
5. Change the port-offset value in `standalone-full-ha.xml` file in the path `standalone_2\configuration`